# Not leveling and not printing correctly

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, troubleshooting, bed-leveling

I have had the Ender 3 S1 for a couple of months but in the last couple of days, prints kept messing up so I decided to try to level it again. Everything moves like it is supposed to but then the light starts blinking red and it stops the leveling process. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have provided very little information for the community to be able to provide an adequate solution. Please [edit] your question to add details/information so that it isn't closed for lack of clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I've read something similar on reddit and according to users it's a known issue fixed about 7 months ago. Try update the FW.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).